# I can't use the command `podman compose` in RHEL 9

Tags: docker-compose, redhat, podman, redhat-containers, podman-compose

It seems I can't use the command `podman compose` in RHEL 9.
If I understand correctly, podman should provide a wrapper for docker-compose and podman-compose as stated here: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-compose.1.html

However, when I try to execute the command `podman compose` I get an error:

```
[root@homeserver ~]# podman compose
Error: unrecognized command `podman compose`
Try 'podman --help' for more information
```

I installed podman-docker and docker-compose (as standalone) and I'm able to run compose files via docker-compose. I'm curious about that wrapper though.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found the issue: podman compose command is available only with podman version 4.7.0 and newer. I'm on RHEL 9 and official repos only offer version 4.6.1.

Comment: As of 2024-01, any idea where can you get 4.7.0 for Ubuntu from?